# How do I perform Array Indexing in R Language?

Tags: r, arrays, indexing

I am new to the R language, so I just want to know how array indexing is done in R. I mean like sorting or any calculations that involve 2D arrays.

Comment: A 2d array is a matrix in R. You should read the Introduction to R.

Comment: Here is a [link ](http://www.bendixcarstensen.com/APC/linalg-notes-BxC.pdf) that you may find useful. One more: [Programming in R](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/02.html#2)

Answer (score 2):

It depends,

To index elements use square brackets: `ar[1]`, or `ar[1,1]` for 2d.
Whole columns and rows are: `ar[,1]` or `ar[1,]`

For sorting, look at the `sort` and `order` functions.

For calculations using 2d arrays, you can have:

Elementwise: `ar1+ar2`, `ar1*ar2`

Inner product: `ar1%*%ar2`

Outer product: `outer(ar1,ar2)` or `ar1%o%ar2`

You must take care that the dimensions of the arrays are correct for what you want to do, though R will automatically try to recycle elements to complete a calculation.

One thing to note is that indexing is 1-based, not 0-based as in most languages, ie the first element is `ar[1]`.

Comment: well, i was writing a code where i had to perform a calculation like this a[i]=(-12*(a[i]+a[i+1])+3*(a[i+2]+a[i+3])+14*a[i+4])/35 now this showed me an error: Error in Ops.data.frame(a[i], a[i + 4]) : + only defined for equally-sized data frames i am unable to understand what kind of error it is..!!! although i tried various possibilities i am unsuccessful so guys please help me out..!! –

Comment: Well it seems that a is a dataframe, so you might want to coerce it to a matrix (`as.matrix(a)`), or extract a vector (by referencing a whole row or column as above). Depends whats in it really.